# Correct way to have an image link in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Something like this might had worked

```
<%= Html.RouteLink("", new { controller = "Article", action = "Details", id = A.ArticleID}, new { @class = "image-link" })%>
```

Except it doesnt like an empty title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could work.

```
<a href="<%= Url.Action("Article", "Details", new {id = A.ArticleID}) %>">
  <img src="<% //Your image src here %>" />
</a>
```

Several people (my company included) have dabbled with creating something that does this in a HtmlHelper, but in the end, it seemed best to do it like this.